# Excel #NAME? error when insert a formula with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

If I insert the following formula in an Excel worksheet with PowerShell:

```
$worksheet.Cells.Item(2,3).Formula = "=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2;FIND("" "";B2)-1); "".""; ""-""))"
```

the cell displays the error value `#NAME?` instead of the calculated value.

However, if I go to the cell, press F2 (to edit the formula) and just press Enter, then the calculated value appears without any error.

Any idea about this? Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this with the below command.

```
$worksheet.Cells.Item(2,3).Formula = "=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2;FIND($([char]34) $([char]34);B2)-1); $([char]34).$([char]34); $([char]34)-$([char]34)))"
```

Comment: Would this not read a lot easier if you saved the char in a small variable or even just the quote itself since they should be functionally the same? or just wrap in single quotes since there are no variables.

Comment: Hi, thanks @Karpak. But this doesn't solve the problem. I don't think it is a problem with escaping quotes. By wrapping the string in single quotes doesn't work neither. The #NAME? error value is still there. I think that it is a bug in Excel, because even recalculation by pressing F9 doesn't work. But pressing F2 + ENTER on a cell shows the resulting value (so no syntax error in the formula neither).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553596/aggregate-formula-not-automatically-calculating-when-written-to-results-spreadsh) helped me find the solution.

Adding '_xlfn.' to the front of each Excel function statement fixed the #NAME errors for me, eg:

```
$worksheet.Cells.Item(2,3).Formula = "=_xlfn.DATEVALUE(_xlfn.SUBSTITUTE(_xlfn.LEFT(B2;_xlfn.FIND("" "";B2)-1); "".""; ""-""))"
```